# Elasticseach failed shard allocation

Tags: elasticsearch

My ES is in yellow state after another one node adding and restarting cluster. I have 4 unassigned shards (from 33), and here is response for one of unassigned shards:

```
{
  "index" : "MY INDEX NAME",
  "shard" : 0,
  "primary" : false,
  "current_state" : "unassigned",
  "unassigned_info" : {
    "reason" : "ALLOCATION_FAILED",
    "at" : "2021-04-29TTIME",
    "failed_allocation_attempts" : 5,
    "details" : "failed shard on node [9yWBUCXXXTIIbiA]: failed to create index,     failure IllegalArgumentException[IOException while reading synonyms_path_path: /etc/elasticsearch/synonyms.txt]; nested: NoSuchFileException[/etc/elasticsearch/synonyms.txt]; ",
    "last_allocation_status" : "no_attempt"
  },
```

And my question is - how I can fix it?

Comment: Looks like my new node realy does not have /etc/elasticsearch/synonyms.txt, but I have no idea who created this file on exsisting nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states

> IOException while reading synonyms_path_path: /etc/elasticsearch/synonyms.txt

This means that in your index settings you have a synonym token filter which doesn't have the right path to your synonym file. You should either make sure that the file exists on the disk or change the path to the file in your index settings.

Comment: Looks like my new node realy does not have /etc/elasticsearch/synonyms.txt, but I have no idea who created this file on exsisting nodes

Can I create it manually? Should I restart ES after that?

Comment: All the nodes should have the same copy of that file, indeed, so you can/should definitely copy/paste it to the new node

Comment: Will allocation start automatically or I need to restart ES?

Comment: You need to restart that new node so the synonyms file can be loaded

Comment: Looks like this was a reason. Thank you!

Comment: Just want to add some steps - added missing file, restarted ES, run `POST /_cluster/reroute?retry_failed=true` to retry allocation and it works

Comment: Good point, if the shard allocation failed after more than 5 retries, you need to trigger the rerouting like you did manually.